# Deploying access policies in Azure

Tags: azure, deployment, devops, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template

Does anyone know if it is really neccessary to insert the actually object-ID in the access policy name property? It seems like it work just fine with any "string".

**"name": "[concat('connection-name'),'/','*object-ID*')]"**

The object-ID is used together with the tenant-ID as one of the identity properties. So why does it have to be used twice according to Microsofts ARM Template description

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/azure-arc-enabled-logic-apps-create-deploy-workflows?tabs=azure-cli

```
 {
       "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections/accessPolicies",
       "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
       "name": "[concat('<connection-name>'),'/','<object-ID>')]",
       "location": "<location>",
       "dependsOn": [
          "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections', parameters('connection_name'))]"
       ],
       "properties": {
          "principal": {
             "type": "ActiveDirectory",
             "identity": {
                "objectId": "<object-ID>",
                "tenantId": "<tenant-ID>"
             }
          }
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In single-tenant Azure Logic Apps, each logic app has an identity that is granted permissions by access policies to use Azure-hosted and managed connections.

The **name** property of the access property in the above JSON code represents the **Connection name** and it is a required field. You can give any **string value** in the **name** property. At the same time it's not mandatory to put object id. But it's recommended to concatenate the object id with connection name to make the connection name **unique** and to avoid ambiguity.

Please check the following [Microsoft.Web/connections/accesspolicies (ARM template)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/connections?tabs=json) documentation for more information.

Comment: That link no longer seem to lead to anything related to access policies